# Ecwid manage customer cart extended option in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created categories in Ecwid store for products and fetch that category product in my website using ecwid api i am passing product-id to next detail page and by using product id parse product data from ecwid product api like quantity ,price and options for that specific product.
Now by using Ecwid addProduct extended option i am trying to pass product data for Add to cart functionality its not working.

```
<script src="//app.ecwid.com/script.js?10998147" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script>
var quant = $('#calquantity').val();
var product = {
  id: "<?php $product_id;?>",
  quantity: quant,
  callback: function(success, product, cart) {
  }
}
Ecwid.Cart.addProduct(productID, function(success, product, cart){
  console.log(success);
  console.log(product.name);
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vitaly from Ecwid team here.

I tried using your code locally and I got this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addProduct' of undefined
at (index):69
```

So this means that the function for adding products is not yet available – Ecwid hasn't loaded yet.

My suggestion is to subscribe to the Ecwid.OnAPILoaded event first, to make sure this function is available first and then execute it. [Documentation](https://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation/subscribe-to-events#ecwid-onapiloaded)

Secondly, there should be correct product ID passed as a first parameter of `Ecwid.Cart.addProduct` function. [Documentation](https://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation/manage-customer-cart#ecwid-cart-addproduct)

So the resulting code will be:

```
<script src="//app.ecwid.com/script.js?10998147" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script>
var quant = $('#calquantity').val();
var productID = <?php echo 103496888;?>;
var product = {
  id: productID,
  quantity: quant,
  callback: function(success, product, cart) {
  }
}

Ecwid.OnAPILoaded.add(function(){
    Ecwid.Cart.addProduct(productID, function(success, product, cart){
        console.log(success);
        console.log(product.name);
    })
})

</script>
```

Thanks! If you have further questions, feel free to contact apps@ecwid.com